# Is a program that never terminates a valid C++ program?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Is a program required to terminate? In other words is a program that that runs forever technically Undefined Behavior? Note this is not about empty loops. Talking about programs that do "stuff" (i.e. observable behavior) forever.

E.g. something like this:

```
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            get_input(); // calls IO
            process();
            put_output(); // calls IO, has observable behavior

            // never break, exit, terminate, etc
        } catch(...)
        {
            // ignore all exceptions
            // don't (re)throw
            // never go out of loop
        }
    }
}
```

This is more of an academic question, as empirically all sane compilers will generate expected code for the above kind of program (assuming of course no other source of UB). And yes, of course there are a lot of programs that never terminate (os, embeded, servers). However the standard is quirky sometimes, thus the question.

---

Tangential: many (some?) definitions of "algorithm" require that **an algorithm must terminate**, i.e. a series of operations that never terminates is not considered an algorithm.

---

Tangential. The halting problem states that there cannot exist an algorithm to determine if an arbitrary program finishes for an input. However for this particular program since there is no branch that leads to getting out of main, the compiler can easily determine the program will never end. This is however irrelevant as the question is language-lawyer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201945/discussion-on-question-by-bolov-is-a-program-that-never-terminates-a-valid-c-p).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is nothing in the C++ standard that requires the program, or any given thread, to terminate. The closest thing to that is [[intro.progress]p1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.progress#1), which says

> The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one of the following:
>
> - terminate,
> - make a call to a library I/O function,
> - perform an access through a volatile glvalue, or
> - perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation.
>
> [ *Note:* This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as removal of empty loops, even when termination cannot be proven.  — *end note* ]

As long as there is *some* observable behavior, eventually, or as long as it spends all its time blocked on an I/O operation or another blocking library call, this doesn't apply, and the program is valid (assuming it meets all the other validity criteria).

Comment: "  an I/O operation or another blocking library call " - the Standard is pretty clear and only lists I/O operations. Why are you adding "or another blocking library call" ? Also, that I/O operation is already included in your earlier "_some_ observable behavior".

Comment: @MSalters `std::mutex::lock()` is a library call that is a synchronization operation, falling under the fourth bullet. So it's not true that only I/O calls are mentioned.

Comment: If it's stuck on *input*, but never gets any, it's debatable whether that counts as observable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. From [`[intro.progress]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress#1)

> The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one
>   of the following:
>
> - terminate,
> - make a call to a library I/O function,
> - perform an access through a volatile glvalue, or
> - perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation.
>
> [ *Note:* This is intended to allow compiler transformations such as removal of
>   empty loops, even when termination cannot be proven. — *end note* ]

Comment: I believe a little description stating that the program does I/O would be advisable.

Comment: So as long as the `get_input` and `put_output` functions in the OPs example "make a call to a library I/O function" the program should be valid even if it doesn't terminate?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude or access a volatile or atomic value, Yes

Comment: curious about the pre c++11 standard, when there wasn't the current memory model.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If functions `get_input`, `process` and `put_input` are not inline - compiler does not know of its implementation, compiles assumes one of the above bullet points and so does not optimize the whole loop away

Comment: `compiler does not know` - This is irrelevant.  Compiler may know and may not know, from a language-layer point of view - the question is if it's valid, in any case.

Comment: It's still _valid_ either way, only just the compiler is allowed (see note) to optimize the loop (or an `if` block, or any such thing) out. This is what compilers demonstrably do, too, in some situations (though often in these situations, some kind of actual UB is involved, too).

Comment: @Damon Notes are non-normative; I think "the implementation may assume" means "a program that does otherwise has UB".

Comment: @DanielH: That's the trouble with these ambiguous wordings, you can't be 100% sure. Though I'm definitively reading "may" as "may", not "otherwise UB". Normally, if it was UB, they would/should write something like "A well-formed program **shall**...", or "otherwise undefined, no diagnostic required" or something similar, but alas, they didn't.

Comment: @bolov There is no memory model. It's a draft of an intuition of a model, not a model. (I was told that such facts that reflect badly on the std and the committee are not welcome here.)

Comment: @DanielH: The authors of the Standard intended that UB didn't mean "Action is forbidden", but rather "the Standard imposes no requirements"; since the Standard makes no effort to fully describe everything necessary to make an implementation *suitable for any particular purpose*, the fact that the Standard doesn't require that an implementation process a construct usefully in no way implies that failure to do so wouldn't render an implementation unsuitable for some purposes.